# RuntimeError: expand(torch.cuda.FloatTensor{[3, 3, 3, 3]}, size=[]): the number of sizes provided (0) must be >= number of dimensions in the tensor(4)

Tags: python, pytorch

Why *[3, 3, 3, 3]* for the [variable w](https://github.com/promach/gdas/blob/main/gdas.py#L469) ?

[image: runtime_error]

Comment: Please don't post code as images (especially unreadable low DPI images). They can't be searched for and can't be cut and pasted by someone else to try your code

Comment: @talonmies picture is now in fullscreen resolution.

Comment: @Ivan there is a github link in the question.  By the way, this issue is now solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is solved using [this github commit](https://github.com/promach/gdas/commit/6ccc7ac0e19f36042b70ae6beecf92895733cbe4)